# Converting WriteableBitmap to stream on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I convert a WriteableBitmap to stream on WP8 platform?

Final goal is to dump the image output produced by native code to the CameraRoll library using `SavePictureToCameraRoll(filename, stream)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can encode your bitmap to stream with WritableBitmap.SaveJpeg method and use this stream as a parameter to MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll. 
Note: before calling MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll don't forget to set the stream position to 0 if you're using a MemoryStream. Like this:

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 100, 100);
fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var m = new MediaLibrary();
m.SavePictureToCameraRoll("test", fileStream);
```