# Transition Effect - HubTile flicker

Tags: windows-phone-8, transition, silverlight-toolkit, flicker

In my application I use the silverlight wp8-toolkit. All pages use this transition-effect:

```
<!--Transition-->
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut" />
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Also all buttons and listboxes an stuff have the Tilt-effect. Only on the MainPage I get this flickering problem. I use 2 HubTiles and some other Buttons with images or icons in them.

Other buttons in this view also start to flicker when pressed and/or returned back via the hardware Back-key. Other views, even other pivot-pages on the same view don't have this behaviour though there are Buttons or LonsgListSelector-elements with Images, a Tilt-effect and the very same Transition.

What are you guys using? Do you use Transitions, HubTiles and/or the Tilt-effect at all?

PerformanceWise the app is still very responsive (I did A LOT of optimization in all parts of the code). So it's not too fancy to work.
Also I get this on a Lumia 520, 920 and 1320. Very different hardware, exactly the same behaviour.

Any hints?

Edit:

I tried to delete this PivotItem's Content and load it again on the next enter, because it never flickered right after the start/on the first transition. Only if repeating. But nop, no change. Still flickers and bugs around. Appreciate any workarond!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could achieve is: Before leaving the View I freeze the HubTiles (IsFreezed-property), "screenshot" them, show an Image with the screenshot, hide the HubTile. When I come back, show the HubTile, hide the Image and unfreeze the HubTiles again.

I still see flickering but not every time and not that much flickering. Plus the freezing saves performance :$

To do the screenshot thing these 2 links helped me: [Converting WriteableBitmap to stream on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913485/converting-writeablebitmap-to-stream-on-wp8) [How do I convert a WriteableBitmap object to a BitmapImage Object in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161665/how-do-i-convert-a-writeablebitmap-object-to-a-bitmapimage-object-in-wpf)

But I won't mark this as solved because I still do have some flickering and it is definitelly related to the transition. My way is a workaround, not a fix.